# Response Headers not setting Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm using devise for authentication . and i want to set some custom response and request headers . I'm trying to do `response.headers['HEADER NAME'] = 'HEADER VALUE'` but it's not setting .
Can anyone help . plus i want to get / set request and response headers in every request

Comment: where are you trying to set it though?

Comment: @uDaY kindly have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35917530/access-token-not-set-in-devise

Comment: did you do it in controller or where?

Comment: In the question you aren't setting any headers as such, can you show snippet of code doing response.headers...?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why `response.headers['HEADER NAME'] = 'HEADER VALUE'` was not working , while it's mentioned in `ruby` document also . But my headers made work with

`headers['Uid'] =   new_auth_header['uid']`